# How to get Document or Compilation from SyntaxNode or SyntaxTree?

Tags: roslyn

I'm writing a `SyntaxRewriter`, so I have a `SyntaxNode` coming into my visit method (actually a `IdentifierNameSyntax`).

What I need to do is work out what symbol the identifier presents, which I can do using a `SemanticModel`.

As I understand it I can get a `SemanticModel` from either a `Document` or a `Compilation`.

So, ideally I want to navigate to the `Document` or `Compilation` from the syntax  node.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you pass the `SemanticModel` to the constructor of your `SyntaxRewriter`?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing. Just wondered if there was a cleaner way. I realise now that SyntaxTrees may not always have parent Document/Compiliations, but still: If they do, it would be nice to be able to navigate to it.

Comment: Answer to this related question may also of use to others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339130/how-to-getsemanticmodel-for-any-syntax-tree-in-referenced-projects-of-project-co/37352848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since there is no guaranteed single Document or Compilation for a tree, in both directions. There might be none, and there also might be *multiple*; if you're typing in the editor we're creating new compilations, reusing syntax trees when possible. Thus, the tree can be in multiple places at once.