# How to GetSemanticModel for any syntax tree in referenced projects of project compilation

Tags: roslyn

When I compile a project (using `MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenProjectAsync().GetCompilationAsync();` I get a `Compilation` back which includes *x* SyntaxTrees for the *x* files within that project. But that project also references other projects. I can see the those projects within the `References` property of the `Compilation`, but it seems that calling `Compliation.GetSemanticModel` does not look through these.

For an arbitrary `SyntaxTree` that is *somewhere* within my project (including referenced projects) do I have to manually search through each referenced `Compilation` of the root project or is there are helper method or some other approach to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call GetSemanticModel for the compilation that contains that tree. So if project A depends on B, and you've walked over to a Syntax Tree in B, you have to use the compilation for B to ask about B. That's because A doesn't actually "know" about anything in B *per se*, it's an opaque box.

Your best opportunity is probably to use the workspace API more. When you called OpenProjectAsync(), grab the `Solution` object from the .Solution property. From there you can walk across all the projects more directly, and if you have a tree you can also do `Solution.GetDocument(tree).GetSemanticModelAsync()`.